# Batch file set /p expressions

Tags: windows, batch-file, set, expression

I'm attempting to make the errorlevel environment variable increase by one every time a certain section of my code is ran. I read in set /? that you can use /p to list an expression that needs to be calculated after the equals sign, however it doesn't seem to change the errorlevel at all.

This is what I have.

```
if not %cd2%==%cd1% (goto :installauto) else set /p errorlevel=(%errorlevel%+1)
```

Thanks for the help, and sorry if this is a noob question. >.<

EDIT: Wow, I'm an idiot. The /a tag is used for expressions. Sorry lol.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to change/create an errorlevel variable, as this is not the errorlevel for other programs.
Then you can not access the "real" errorlevel anymore.

You could better do this with an other variable and exit the bacth file with exit /B

```
set myErr=0
if not %cd2%==%cd1% (
    goto :installauto
) else (
    set /a myErr=myErr+1
)
exit /b %myErr%
```

Comment: Huh. I realized that I could do it this way, however I didn't realize that my current way would screw up the errorlevel variable, so I figured I'd save space. Thanks for the tip.